# Firebase, Anyway to create name dynamically

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
fredNameRef.set({ first: 'Fred', last: 'Flintstone' });
```

I want to create 'name' which is first and last name dynamically.
For Example :

```
var x = first_1;
var y = last_1;
fredNameRef.set({ x: 'Fred', y: 'Flintstone' });
```

Comment: Can I ask what the use case is? Dynamic names can be tricky and can often lead to coding yourself into a corner. You may want to consider moving up a level in your data model; perhaps leveraging a dictionary or an array?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about auto-calculated value, Firebase doesn't have such a feature. You will have to pre-calculate the value as you write the name to the database:

```
fred = { first: 'Fred', last: 'Flintstone' };
fred.name = fred.first + ' ' + fred.last;
refNameRef.set(fred);
```

You could even validate that write operations don't violate this rule:

```
".validate": "newData.child('name').val() === (newData.child('first').val() + ' ' + newData.child('last').val())"
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot. Actually, I'm a newbie in firebase.